# Find particular string in Heroku logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, heroku

I am logging some errors by doing this in my Rails app:

```
logger.error "MY ERROR STRING"
```

How can I look in heroku logs to find that line?

I know how to do `heroku logs --tail` and `heroku logs -n 500` ,but how can I find a specific string in the logs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `heroku logs -t | grep "term"` is great for filtering current log events. However, Heroku [retains a max of 1500 lines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log_retrieval) of log output, so even if you do `heroku logs -n 1500 -t` you won't see log events that occurred prior to that log window.

The better approach is to use a logging add-on like [Papertrail](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/papertrail) that retains your logs for a greater period of time and makes your full log history searchable.

Of course, it also possible that the log event you think is triggering in your code isn't.

Comment: How to solve same purpose `heroku logs -t | grep "term"` using Windows 'FINDSTR' command?

Comment: To user grep with windows, install grep software, and add the grep path to your local environment variables

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `| grep "search term"` after your `heroku logs -n 500` statement

so something like: `heroku logs -n 500 | grep "MY ERROR STRING"`

Comment: I still don't see it. Is it any configuration needed to be able to see the logs that are filled in logger.error in Heroku?

Comment: This only searches your most immediate logs. If this log output didn't happen recently you won't see it with this approach.

Comment: Well in his example he is only looking for the last 500 entries or tailing, so I think he's looking for recent logs

Answer (score 0):

For a windows users,

`heroku logs -n 100 -a appname | find "wordToFind"`

you can change 100 to other number from 0 to 1500, that is the last 1500 logs from you heroku application